# which keychain attribute can i used to save a small NSArray

Tags: iphone, ios, nsarray, keychain

I have an NSArray of server addresses I would like to put into my keychain. The reason why I am trying to do this all be it not imperative to keep the addresses secret, it would be preferable.

Here is an example of how I have saved other values to my keychain:

```
// Set up keychain
KeychainItemWrapper* keychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"KeychainTest" accessGroup:nil];
    [keychain setObject:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked) forKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccessible)];

//write to keychain
[keychain setObject:@"1" forKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrService)];
[keychain setObject:@"example@email.com" forKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccount)];
[keychain setObject:@"MySuperSecretPassword" forKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)];

//Log to check values
NSLog(@"%@ %@, %@",[keychain objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrService)], [keychain objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccount)], [keychain objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)]);
```

I would like to know the best way for saving an NSArray into my keychain. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/granoff/Lockbox ... look into this project, it deals with storing data in key chain. Should help.